# wp_nav_menu: output featured image of each page listing

Tags: pages, menus, images, list

Context: I am building a portfolio index where I can sort the individual project links in my sidebar by priority of appearance. I've successfully done this using the wp_nav_menu(), where each project is represented by the text name, and then I can move each Page's priority of appearance. What I get is something like this:

Projects Menu List:

- Project A Page
- Project B Page
- Project C Page

Now, I'd like to extend this feature by outputting the featured image associated with every individual project page so that it looks something like this:

Project Menu List:

- Project A Page [+ Featured Image associated with Project A Page]
- Project B Page [+ Featured Image associated with Project B Page]
- Project C Page [+ Featured Image associated with Project C Page]

Is this possible with the wp_nav_menu() call? If so, any clues on how to extend it further? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Honestly I have not used wp-nav-menu much other than just using it for a menu. I am thinking in your case it might be more semantic to create a custom-post-type for "Projects" and then list those (rather than using the wp-menu as a Project sorter) 
. You can use the plugin "Post Types Order" to order your custom posts the way you want (works the same as arranging the order of menus..with a drag and drop).

The advantage to using Custom Post Types is that there is a lot more flexibility to use them how you want.
So, in short:

- Create a custom post type for "Projects"
- Install Post Types Order to order your Projects
- On the page (or sidebar) where you want to list your projects use the code below, add the following snippet.

---

```
$example = new WP_Query( 'post_type' => 'projects','showposts' => '20' );
// gives the title for each project
if ( $example->have_posts() ) : 
    while ( $example->have_posts() ) : 
    the_post(); 
    ?>
    <div class="project" >  
        <!-- thumbnail -->
        <span class="project-thumb">   
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        </span>
        <!-- end thumbnail -->
        <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4><!--title -->
    </div><!--#project -->
    <?php 
    endwhile; 
endif;
```

Comment: ' <?php query_posts('post_type= Projects','showposts=20'); ?>
      <!--gives the title for each project -->
        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
         <div class="project" > 
         <!--thumbnail -->
         <span class="project-thumb">   
          <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
         </span>
         <!--#project=thumb -->
         <h4>-<?php the_title(); ?></h4><!--title -->
          </div><!--#project -->
        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>'

Comment: You have those `{}` brackets above the editor to format code and backticks to format code in comments or chat. If you click "help" on the right side of a comment, you'll see the formatting help windo slide down and a "Learn more..." Link at the end of the yellow box.

Comment: Yes, I know about the brackets. They are on there now surrounding my code,  but for some reason on this post only the code is not showing.

Comment: Adam: Thanks, this method looks better than the Menu Pages method! I'll look into it, thanks!

Comment: @adam.robertson Some notes: The formatting problem started with the list (use `*` instead of `-`). Also, you need to add the values for the args array as seen above. You mixed query style input with array input. If you write `'post_type= Projects'`, then array would that see as the input value and not the according key. As it's an associative array, it wouldn't go anywhere.